# Rails share models between microservices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Our app is starting to become quite the monolith and seeing some scaling pain points. We have some long running page loads that kill the request queue for the rest of the app. Been thinking about it for a few days and have been thinking to abstract out to some microservices could release some pressure.

Been doing a lot of reading on microservices and have read you can have all your services share the same DB or create a new DB for each service - both are acceptable based on what I've read. Our data is quite large so it would be an easier abstraction to share the same DB.

I sat down this morning determined to start a new Rails JSON API app to abstract out some business analytics pages to a new service but quickly realized this new app won't have any of the model files etc in it for ActiveRecord to use. How do people get around this when they are sharing a DB with all services?

Edit:

I'm planning on this service to run off a follower read-only slave DB as well to help with the load.

Comment: This is a bit more "whiteboard" of a question than we allow here on Stack Overflow...

Comment: Hmm suggestions on where to ask then? @Makoto

Comment: Sharing a DB doesn't require sharing all the models. Microservices usually aim for a single service owning any given domain model. How might you structure this app or change your domain boundaries such that you don't need to share models? Alternately if that's unacceptable maybe you're looking for a different architecture rather than "microservice"?

Comment: @Jonah I guess for this particular service its necessary though since its an analytics service that will query many different models in the system.

Comment: Depending on the problem you need to solve you might not need a separate app here at all. Consider if you could deploy the same code as a distinct app with conditionally available routes so that your analytics requests could hit a different (sub)domain and not add load on your normal production instances. Alternately look at how multiple engines within an app could be used to share models. Unfortunately it's hard to offer a useful architecture suggestion here without knowing entirely too much about your app and team.

Comment: @Jonah interesting idea. I'm worried about scale though. Our user base has the potential to double very quickly and I want the best architecture for the long run. I inherited the app from a contractor a few years ago and the foundation he laid isn't ideal.

Comment: why don't you simply copy the model files over to the other project?

Comment: additionally [`ActiveResource`](https://github.com/rails/activeresource) might be beneficial to you depending on your implementation. I will allow a rest based model to live elsewhere but act relatively native. e.g. if you called `Resource.find` it would actually make a web request to the endpoint specified and return as an `ActiveModel` like object.

Comment: @maxpleaner that wouldn't be DRY and would be a pain to maintain.

Comment: @engineersmnky looks cool. Ill look into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use libraries like `Sequel` instead of `ActiveRecord`, you could rely less on the model layer and make your code/queries closer to the database, I don't think it would solve all your problems though as you would need to update your code everywhere after each migration. One thing you can do however, is package part of your model layer as `Gems` to share across applications.

"We have some long running page loads that kill the request queue for the rest of the app."
 => Can it be solved by making some of your requests asynchronous? The backend of the web app is not supposed to do any heavy lifting, it should be done by crons/other.

Comment: Ya we have sidekiq some long running jobs. Might have to look into making it work on page renders too.